# Does anyone know about Firebase attribution mechanism? And attribution window length?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Does anyone know about Firebase attribution windows? Are they customizable? What is the time period of attribution window (7, 10 days)? I have looked everywhere but can not find information. As well as for attribution waterfall. Any insights on that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a Google product and is closely tied with Google Ad Networks ([AdWords](https://firebase.google.com/docs/adwords/) and [AbMob](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/)). Once [Firebase is linked with AdWords](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/), an advertiser can set a codeless Ad Campaign and track it in the Firebase Console. Similar is with the [AdMob integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase). The duration of campaign can be customized in the AdWords Console dashboard.

If you want to start an app campaign with a third party Ad Network, you can do so and add the tracking URL generated in the Firebase Console in the campaign set up of the preferred network. The conversions will be reported in the *Firebase Console --> Analytics --> Attribution --> Conversion Events* table to be further filtered as Source, Medium and Campaign. The data can also be further obtained for date range.

Take a look at this [blogpost](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/understanding-attribution-in-firebase.html) for more details on this topic.